# Erro NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

Tenho um programa que faz a autenticação biométrica em duas versões:

1) O usuário seleciona o arquivo binário via `javax.swing` da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Busca extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   ...
   java.io.FileInputStream fis = null; fis = new            
   Java.io.FileInputStream(fs_at.getSelectedFile()); nLoadLen = fis.read(loadData); 
   int retornoexp = exportEngine.ImportFIR(loadData, nLoadLen, nMinType, hLoadFIR);
```

2) Na outra versão, rodo o programa via linha de comando e o arquivo é passado como parâmetro, ficando assim:

```
public int autentic_python(String arquivo) { 
   ..... 
   fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(arquivo); 
   nLoadLen = fis.read(loadData); 
   int retornoexp = exportEngine.ImportFIR(loadData, nLoadLen, nMinType, hLoadFIR);
```

O problema é que na segunda versão dá o erro `Java.lang.NullPointerException` no comando `exportEngine`.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Verificou se `nLoadLen` é maior que zero? Pode ser que nao tenha nada a ler em `loadData`

Comment: Fernando, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Verifique se o arquivo está no caminho correto. Tente usar caminho absoluto caso esteja usando relativo. Verifique também se o parâmetro da minha de comando está realmente sendo passado para o método. Enfim, só com essas informações é difícil dizer o problema, então tente depurar e completar a pergunta com mais informações, editando-a, para que possamos lhe ajudar melhor. Abraço!